# unbound method f() must be called with x instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python, magicmock

Here is my class:

```
class GoogleCloudLayer:

    def deleteMachine(self, machineName):
        return machineName + ' is dead. (stubbed)'
```

It works:

```
>>> gc = GoogleCloudLayer()
>>> gc.deleteMachine('test')
test is dead (stubbed)
```

But I want to use in test and I want to have the `assert_called_with` method defined on it:

```
from mock import MagicMock
#Stubbing with itself just so it will have the `assert_called_with` method defined on it
GoogleCloudLayer.deleteMachine = MagicMock(side_effect = GoogleCloudLayer.deleteMachine)
```

But then I get

```
>>> gc = GoogleCloudLayer()
>>> gc.deleteMachine('test')
unbound method deleteMachine() must be called with GoogleCloudLayer instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

If I change production code to `gc.deleteMachine(gc, 'test')` it works. 
But we don't want that , do we?

Comment: awesome!  that did it

Comment: add it as answer, i'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` can be useful in this situation, try:

```
GoogleCloudLayer.createMachine = MagicMock(side_effect = lambda *args, **kwargs: GoogleCloudLayer.createMachine)
```